# Remove Emoji from string in Lua

Tags: string, replace, lua, emoji

As the title states, I am trying to filter Emoji characters from input strings in Lua.
This is for use within a telegram bot I have been working on.
I have a command that will break if Emoji are passed into it.

```
'Hello World '
```

to

```
'Hello world'
```

Comment: can try `str = 'Hello World '; print(str:gsub("\xF0\x9F..", ""))` not a perfect solution but should help you get started.

Comment: "I have a command that will break if Emoji are passed into it." That's the X of your XY problem. Fix that instead.

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica The problem there is that the API I am working with does not allow emoji characters. More specifically, [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setchatadministratorcustomtitle).
As it states `New custom title for the administrator; 0-16 characters, emoji are not allowed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I see three things you could do. You're currently asking how to solve 3.

1. prevent emojis from being entered by ignoring anything you don't want to be entered
2. if something you don't want has been entered, deny that input with an error message
3. remove anything you don't want from the string befor you process it

To remove something from a Lua string you can simply replace it with an empty string.
Use [string.gsub](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) and a [pattern](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1) that matches all emojis.

I suggest you give this a read http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUnicode